# How to change file name in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

After uploading a file in Google Colab with the code below

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

How can I change its name?

Comment: https://medium.com/my-world-with-python/how-to-rename-multiple-files-or-data-sets-which-is-in-google-drive-using-python-af6233849ee7

Comment: rename file option

Comment: I would like to avoid mounting the drive possibly. isn't a quick line of code. I need to rename only 1 file.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
src = os.listdir()[1]   #find out the file name which u want to rename using indexing
dst ='image.jpg'        #change it to the destination name
os.rename(src, dst)     #rename it
os.listdir()[1]         #access the renamed file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you guess right that 'uploaded' holds your file name. And yes, you can access it for renaming purposes, like this:

```
import os
dst ='image.jpg' 
os.rename(list(uploaded.keys())[0], dst)
```

Now, if you have several files uploaded, you should pay attention on which file to choose, since 'uploaded' is a dictionary and it is not guaranteed to be sorted in any way.